# Evaluating $\frac{1}{\pi} \mathrm{p.v.} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{(1+ix)^n}{(1-ix)^{(n+1)}(x-y)} \; \mathrm{d}x$ without complex analysis

Tags: integration

I was reading a paper about computing Hilbert Transforms (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153449?seq=4) via numerical methods, and this integral was evaluated in the proof of Theorem 1.

Is there a way to compute $$\frac{1}{\pi} \mathrm{p.v.} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{(1+ix)^n}{(1-ix)^{(n+1)}(x-y)} \; \mathrm{d}x$$ without resorting to some sort of complex analysis argument?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to avoid complex analysis methods? You can rearrange it so that you have real and imaginary parts that are both rational functions but they won't necessarily be that nice to evaluate.

Comment: @ConMan Mostly out of curiosity. :)